# How to style the tabularx inside a tcolorbox?

Tags: tabularx, tcolorbox

I want to set the `boxrule` of a `tcolorbox`, but when I add a `tabularx` to it, it is suddenly ignored.

[image: box widths of tcolorboxes]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=5pt,tabularx={l}]
hello world
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=5pt]
hello world
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

How do I enforce the boxrule?

What I want to do is force the frame width to match `\hline`.

Comment: I am running `tcolorbox` v4.20.

Comment: Change the order of the pgf keys: `\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx={l},boxrule=5pt]
hello world
\end{tcolorbox}`. That is, `boxrule=5pt` needs to go after `tabularx={l}`.

Comment: Oh, this is just evil! I've been at it for over half an hour. Works.

Comment: Being a cat helps. ;-)

Comment: If you want the rep, feel free to turn the comment into an answer.

Comment: I'd like to leave this decision up to you. If you feel it is useful I will be happy to add an answer, but certainly not for the sake of accumulating points.

Comment: Certainly useful for anybody in my situation. I was searching SE and google up and down in a frustrated frenzy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pgf keys are "only" some cleverly packaged macros. Therefore the order in which you use them matters, simply because the order in which you execute macros matters, too. So you may want to put the key that sets the line width "as late as possible". In your case, there are only two keys so you may want to put `boxrule=5pt` last.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=5pt,tabularx={l}]
hello world
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx={l},boxrule=5pt]
hello world
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=5pt]
hello world
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]